# Razor datepicker not selecting any value in update

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, kendo-ui

i have inline editing grid with datepicker. This is working fine if i use local database(PC database) but not working if i use remote database

**shared/editortemplate/DateTime.cshtml**

```
@model DateTime?


@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m).Format("M/dd/yyyy"))
```

**View:**

```
columns.Bound(p => p.DateCompleted).Format("{0:d}").Width(80)
```

**Model:**

```
[UIHint("Date")]
 [DisplayName("Date Completed")]
 public DateTime? DateCompleted { get; set; }
```

when i tried to update and pick another date the tried to save, the date value become null and it weird is only happen if i connect via remote database

please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have a difference in how SQL is interpreting the date format when you're pushing it. A local machine cultural settings are probably different on your remote sql server and are not parsing the date properly that's coming out of your .NET app.

Comment: I was restore the local database backup from the local database server

Comment: Sorry, you loaded a local database backup from a local database? How does this resolve what I suggested, it's the differences between servers where I think the problem lies.

Comment: Sorry, i was restore the database from the server database.